# Javascript property delegation and prototype

Tags: javascript

Lately I have come up with how Javascript works with inheritance and share properties, what is  property delegation? I know that if I create a function outside one, the property will be assigned to the global object, (the window browser) and that window object is a property of object Object… so does that mean that Object always hold properties which contain all the objects in the browser? thanks for the answers.

Comment: I don't think "property delegation" is the right terminology.

Comment: Your question doesn’t make much sense as it is. Could you re-word it?

Comment: I think you've mixed DOM objects and JS objects here. Please can you elaborate the question?

Comment: What do you mean by "*that window object is a property of object Object*"?

Comment: I mean about the Object which holds all the other objects in the browser, window, document, arrays…

Comment: sorry I think I mixed some different topics